# Multiple Data Types in a stack in C

Tags: c, types, stack

So I am doing a simple infix calculator.
I am having trouble of storing a char and a double on one stack.

First I attempted to separate the operands and operator as seen in the code below but later on I realize I would be gone in a big trouble.

I'm a newbie also in using unions 
What should I do to store a char and a double on one stack only?

here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


typedef union{
    char c;
    double d;
} Union;

 typedef struct Node{
    Union data;
    struct Node *link;
 } Node;

 typedef struct Stack{
    Node *top;
 }Stack;

 void initialize_stack(Stack *stack)
 {
    stack->top=NULL;
 }

  int is_stack_empty(Stack *stack)
 {
    return(stack->top==NULL);
 }

 void push_c(Stack *stack, char x)
 {
    Node *node=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(node==NULL)
    {
        printf("Sorry no enough memory\n");
    }
    else
    {
        node->data.c=x;
        node->link=NULL;
        if(is_stack_empty(stack))
        {
            stack->top=node;
        }
        else
        {
            node->link=stack->top;
            stack->top=node;
        }       
    }
 }

void push_d(Stack *stack, double x)
{
    Node *node=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

   if(node==NULL)
   {
       printf("Sorry no enough memory\n");
   }
   else
   {
        node->data.d=x;
        node->link=NULL;
        if(is_stack_empty(stack))
        {
            stack->top=node;
        }
        else
        {
            node->link=stack->top;
            stack->top=node;
        }       
    } 
}

void pop(Stack *stack)
{
    Node *runner=stack->top;
    if(is_stack_empty(stack))
    {
         printf("Stack is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        stack->top=stack->top->link;
        free(runner);
     }
 }



void print_stack_c(Stack *stack)
{
    Node *runner=stack->top;
    if(is_stack_empty(stack))
    {
        printf("Stack is empty.\n");
    }
     else
    {
        while(runner!=NULL)
       {
            printf("%c,",runner->data.c);
            runner=runner->link;
        }
         printf("\n");
     }
 }

 void print_stack_d(Stack *stack)
 {
     Node *runner=stack->top;
     if(is_stack_empty(stack))
     {
         printf("Stack is empty.\n");
      }
     else
     {
         while(runner!=NULL)
         {
             printf("%.4f,",runner->data.d);
             runner=runner->link;
          }
         printf("\n");
     }
 }

 int main(){
    char input[150],output[150];
    int i;
    double j;
    char a[20]="";
    char b[20]="";
    char c[10],d[10]="",e[10]="";
    struct Stack operand;
    struct Stack operator;
    struct Stack tempstack; 


    initialize_stack(&tempstack);
    initialize_stack(&operand);
    initialize_stack(&operator);

    scanf("%s",input); //store input to a string 


    //convert infix to postfix
    for(i=0;i<strlen(input)-1;i++){

    if(input[i]==' '){
        continue;
    }
    else if(input[i]=='('){

        push_c(&tempstack,input[i]);
    }

    else if(isdigit((unsigned char)input[i]) || input[i] == '.'){
    strcpy(a,b);//clear
    while(isdigit((unsigned char)input[i]) || input[i] == '.'){
    strncat(a,&input[i],1);
    i++;        
    }

    j=atof(a);
    push_d(&operand,j);
    }

    else{ //operand


    }

    } 

    print_stack_c(&tempstack);
    print_stack_d(&operand);
    }
```

Comment: You need also store type to know what is inside union. You can do it like this typedef union {
    char c;
    double d;
} value;

enum {
    double_t,
    operatuion_t
} valuetype;

typedef struct {
    value v;
    valuetype t;
} stack_elem;

Comment: Like LZ041 said, in order to use the data stored in the union properly you must know whether a character or double was stored.  You can do that by adding some sort of flag to you Node structure, whether its an enumeration or some other data type where you can store two different states, one that indicates that the data union contains a character and a state that indicates that it stores a double.

You would set the flag in Node accordingly at the same time you store the data and then check the flag before retrieving the data.

Comment: *I am having trouble of storing a char and a double on one stack.* What is the trouble you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SUCCESS 0

typedef enum DATATYPES_E
    {
    DATATYPE_DOUBLE,
    DATATYPE_CHAR
    } DATATYPES_T;

typedef union DATA_U
   {
   char   c;
   double d;
   } DATA_T;

typedef struct NODE_S
   {
   DATA_T         data;
   DATATYPES_T    dataType;
   struct NODE_S *link;
   } NODE_T;

typedef struct STACK_S
   {
   NODE_T *top;
   } STACK_T;

int StackPushChar(STACK_T *stack, char x)
   {
   int     rCode=SUCCESS;
   NODE_T *node;

   errno=0;
   node=malloc(sizeof(NODE_T));
   if(!node)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   node->dataType = DATATYPE_CHAR;
   node->data.c=x;
   node->link=NULL;
   if(stack->top)
      {
      node->link=stack->top;
      stack->top=node;
      }
   else
      stack->top=node;

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }

int StackPushDouble(STACK_T *stack, double x)
   {
   int     rCode=SUCCESS;
   NODE_T *node;

   errno=0;
   node=malloc(sizeof(NODE_T));
   if(!node)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   node->dataType =  DATATYPE_DOUBLE;
   node->data.d=x;
   node->link=NULL;
   if(stack->top)
      {
      node->link=stack->top;
      stack->top=node;
      }
   else
      stack->top=node;

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }

 void StackPrint(STACK_T *stack)
   {
   NODE_T *runner=stack->top;
   if(!stack->top)
      {
      printf("Stack is empty.\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   while(runner)
      {
      switch(runner->dataType)
         {
         case DATATYPE_DOUBLE:
            printf("%.4f,",runner->data.d);
            break;

         case DATATYPE_CHAR:
            printf("%c,", runner->data.c);
            break;
         }

      runner=runner->link;
      }

   printf("\n");

CLEANUP:

   return;
   }

int main()
   {
   int     rCode   = SUCCESS;
   STACK_T stack =
      {
      .top=NULL
      };

   rCode=StackPushDouble(&stack, 3.1415926535);
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "StackPushDouble() reports %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   rCode=StackPushChar(&stack, '+');
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "StackPushChar() reports %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   rCode=StackPushDouble(&stack, 6.02E23);
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "StackPushDouble() reports %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   rCode=StackPushChar(&stack, '=');
   if(rCode)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "StackPushChar() reports %d %s\n", rCode, strerror(rCode));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

    StackPrint(&stack);

CLEANUP:

    return(rCode);
    }
```